# How to properly instantiate a tile map in a grid

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, hierarchy, tiles, 2d-games

So I am making in unity game that is a 2D platformer runner, currently I made some Tilemaps that are platforming sections and then prefab, then i am trying to generate the platforming, but when I do it with a script for managing the generation of level, Instead of making the whole section it compress it in a single cell of my current grid.

```
public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float PLAYER_GENERATION_DISTANCE = 200f;
    [SerializeField] private Transform StartLevel;
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> levelPartsList;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player; 

    private Vector3 lastEndPosition;
    
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        lastEndPosition = StartLevel.Find("endPosition").position;
    }

    void Update(){
        if (Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, lastEndPosition) < PLAYER_GENERATION_DISTANCE)
        {
            print("I am WOrking!!!");
            SpawnLevelPart();
        }
    }

    private void SpawnLevelPart()
    {
        Transform selectRandomType = levelPartsList[Random.Range(0,levelPartsList.Count)];
        Transform lastLevelPartTransform = SpawnLevelPart(selectRandomType,lastEndPosition);
        lastEndPosition = lastLevelPartTransform.Find("endPosition").position;
    }

    private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Transform levelPart,Vector3 spawnPosition)
    {
        Transform levelPartTransform = Tilemap.Instantiate(levelPart,spawnPosition,Quaternion.identity);
        return levelPartTransform;

    }
}
```

[The compressed Tile map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJW9D.png)
[The prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL4VS.png)

When I manually put the Tilemap in the grid it works fine but how do I instantiate and then move it to the grid component as a child?

Answer (score 0):

How to instantiate tilemap prefab right? - You just need to instantiate it as a child of object with "grid" component:

```
[SerializeField] private Transform objectWithGrid; 

private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Transform levelPart,Vector3 spawnPosition)
{
    Transform levelPartTransform = Tilemap.Instantiate(levelPart, objectWithGrid,spawnPosition,Quaternion.identity);
    return levelPartTransform;

}
```

Second param of instantiate is a transform, that will be a parent of new instantiated object.